# Nagios plugin gives “no output returned” using compiled perl

Tags: perl

I have a custom nagios plugin which is written in Perl. For complicated political reasons I am required to hide the source code of this plugin. The only way I found to do this was by using perlc (http://marginalhacks.com/Hacks/perlc).

In the words of author:

"Takes a single perl script, converts the block using a simple encoding with an optionally defined key. The script is decoded at runtime and fed to the perl library, to avoid it getting in the hands of the user."

The problem I am getting is that Nagios shows "No output returned from plugin" when I used the compiled version of the plugin. The raw perl source works just fine.

After debugging for a while I narrowed the problem down to using exit in perl. I.e

This works fine when compiled.

```
print "OK: Everything is working fine.\n";
```

This however does not work and results in ""No output returned from plugin"

```
print "OK: Everything is working fine.\n";
exit 1;
```

It doesn't matter how I exit (0 1 2 or 3) I still get the same problem.

Comment: Crosspost at perlmonks: http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1095895

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cross-posted PerlMonks thread](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1095895), the issue was resolved by enabling autoflushing:

```
$| = 1;
```

From [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> - HANDLE->autoflush( EXPR )
> - $OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH
> - $|
>
>   If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or
>     print on the currently selected output channel. Default is 0
>     (regardless of whether the channel is really buffered by the system or
>     not; `$|` tells you only whether you've asked Perl explicitly to flush
>     after each write). STDOUT will typically be line buffered if output is
>     to the terminal and block buffered otherwise. Setting this variable is
>     useful primarily when you are outputting to a pipe or socket, such as
>     when you are running a Perl program under rsh and want to see the
>     output as it's happening.

See the article [Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) for more details.